# Angularfire2 querying with timestamp

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Angular and Firebase. And I come from SQL queries, so querying in firebase can be tricky for me.

I've this object structure in firebase: (**[EDIT]** - The real JSON structure in firebase)

```
"acceleration-values" : {
    "-KyGw8gDF4thAie8_hYk" : {
      "timestamp" : "2017/10/1_15:26:24:712",
      "value" : 2.3403
    },
    "-KyGw8if5_oCaqy1b9Y8" : {
      "timestamp" : "2017/10/1_15:26:24:912",
      "value" : 4.38385
    },
    "-KyGw8ou_viOW6hKARTC" : {
      "timestamp" : "2017/10/1_15:26:25:310",
      "value" : 0.28864
    },
    "-KyGw8yJw_cgwuB4tYyu" : {
      "timestamp" : "2017/10/1_15:26:25:912",
      "value" : 1.6212
    },
    "-KyGw96gH7O6h3oPAyCf" : {
      "timestamp" : "2017/10/1_15:26:26:512",
      "value" : 4.36751
    }
  }
```

And I need to get acceleration objects when 'timestamp' is equal or greater than some value.

I've searched in angular and firebase docs with no success. I tried to use 'startAt' with no success because maybe I don't know how to properly use it. I think my issue is so specific that docs can't help.

If I could get some help I would be very grateful.
Thank you, anyway.

=== **[EDIT]** ===

As @Chris mentioned, I could store the data as a map. To be honest that solution looks good and simple. 
I only have to questions:
  1. How could I retrieve the key (timestamp) besides the value?
  2. If I implemented that solution could I add an user? Like having something like this:

```
- acceleration-values:{
        - user_1: {
            - 2017-11-08T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
            - 2017-11-09T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
        }
        - user_2: {
            - 2017-11-08T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
            - 2017-11-08T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
            - 2017-11-08T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
            - 2017-11-09T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
        }
        - user_3: {
            - 2017-11-08T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
            - 2017-11-08T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
            - 2017-11-09T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
        }
    }
```

If I could have something shown in the Edit, it would be awesome.

Thank you again.

=== **[EDIT - 2]** ===

This is what I have. It gives me all the values in firebase but, as said earlier, I only need the values (and the timestamp) after a given timestamp.

```
this.accelerationValuesRef = this.db.list('/acceleration-values');

this.accelerationSubscription = this.accelerationValuesRef.snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(action => {
      const data = action.payload.val();
      const $key = action.payload.key;
      return {$key, ...data}
    });
  }).subscribe(data => this.accelerationValues = data);
```

Thank you all for your attention.

=== **[EDIT - 3]** ===

(Everything I do is an assumption because I've never worked with this)

After try and error I think I'm getting somewhere.

Now I have this:

```
this.accelerationValuesRef = this.db.list('/acceleration-values',
  ref => ref.startAt(this.getYesterday())
);

this.accelerationSubscription = this.accelerationValuesRef.snapshotChanges()
 .map(actions => {
   return actions.map(action => {
     const data = action.payload.val();
     const $key = action.payload.key;
     return {$key, ...data}
    });
  }).subscribe(data => this.accelerationValues = data);
```

Note: 'getYesterday()' is a function that returns the yesterday date.

I've created a reference to my list (acceleration-values) and to start at a given parameter. My problem is: how can I say I want to reference to the 'timestamp' variable?

Thank you for your all attention and time.

Comment: Since it should be fairly straightforward (and indeed requires `startAt`), the problem is likely in the details of how you used it. Can you update your question to show the code that you've tried?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I've tried so many things and deleted to try others and now I don't have any solution of how I used it... I've read the docs and tried to replicate for my problem with no success. If you have a possible solution I would like to hear it please.
P.S.: The edit is for the solution presented by Chris, but you agree with that, you could elaborate as well.
Thank you anyway for your time

Answer (score -1):

As Frank mentioned it is indeed possible.

The data structure you have shown above looks like an array, this wont work. You need to store it as a map. Your data structure could look like this:

```
    movidadomus: {
    - acceleration-values:{
        //Note the different date format, you can't use '/' in a key in firebase
        2017-11-08T01:00:00+01:00: X.XXXX
        2017-11-08T01:00:00+02:00: X.XXXX
        2017-11-08T01:00:00+03:00: X.XXXX
    }
}
```

then you can query like this `ref.child('movidadomus').child('acceleration-values').orderByKey().startAt('2017-11-08T01:00:00+01:00')`

If you are new to firebase, and are just starting using the database, I would recommend using their new product [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/). Unless you need realtime functionality (Firestore still provides this to a certain extend) then that is the way to go in my opinion.